# Error 91 Using For Loop with XMLHttpRequest VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to scrape a site for the contents of various HTML tags. I am using an array of html tags against an array of URLs.

```
Sub pArse(UserForm4_HiddenList_Text)

Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
'Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim hero_true_Val As Integer
Dim down_var As Integer
Dim bill_array_redim
Dim element_tag As String
Dim address_count As Integer


        hero_true_Val = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), True)
        down_var = 1
        bill_array_redim = Split(UserForm4_HiddenList_Text, Chr(10))

ReDim address_array(hero_true_Val)

For Z = 2 To 6
        If Sheets("resource").Cells(Z, 2).Value <> "False" Then
            address_count = address_count + 1
            address_array(address_count) = Sheets("resource").Cells(Z, 1).Value
        End If

Next Z



Sheets("Sheet1").Select

For url_stack = 0 To UBound(bill_array_redim)
    Sheets("sheet1").Cells(down_var, 1) = bill_array_redim(url_stack)

    For what_to_check = 1 To address_count


        With http
        .Open "GET", bill_array_redim(url_stack), False
        .send
        Do While http.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
        Loop


        End With

                Dim html As New HTMLDocument
                With html
                .body.innerHTML = http.responseText
                ' the next line is where the error occurs 
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(down_var, 2).Value = .querySelector(address_array(what_to_check)).innerText
                End With

                down_var = down_var + 1

    Next what_to_check
Next url_stack

UserForm4.Hide
End Sub
```

A user clicks a command button which then feeds in an array of URLs (UserForm4_HiddenList_Text). The code then checks for the existence of the word "true" in the sheet named "resource." This generates an array of terms to check for.

the problem I'm having is that on the second iteration of the what_to_check loop, I'm getting

> error 91 : Object or with block variable not set

I'm unsure of what the issue is here and it only seems to occur if I pass in two html tags rather than one.

edit: thanks for replying Cindy. The error location is bolded. The message is "Object or with block variable not set."

Comment: Which line is causing the error? And what's the text of the error message, please? Note that you can use the [edit] link to add this directly to your question.

Comment: @CindyMeister error 91 would be the classic "Object variable or With block variable not set" ;-)

Comment: The error means you're making a member call against an object that doesn't exist, i.e. its reference is `Nothing`, a *null pointer*. You have a lot of chained member calls, which makes this particular problem much harder to debug than it needs to be. Take the result of `address_array(what_to_check)` into its own local variable, then take `.querySelector(thatVariable)` into its own local variable, then make the cell value `= thatOtherVariable.innerText` - *then* you'll know exactly which object reference is `Nothing`, and you can act accordingly.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon many many thanks. I'll take a look into that.

Comment: Arrays starts with 0 index and the last item would be ubound(array) -1.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was being given an error I either didn't fully understand or wasn't very clear. The issue was that the response didn't have the tag inside it that I was looking for as it wasn't present on the site. By using:

```
With html
         .body.innerHTML = http.responseText
         If .body.contains(.querySelector(tag_array(tag_array_index_no))) 
Then
        Sheets(1).Range(Cells(down_var, 2).Address).Value = 
 tag_array(tag_array_index_no)
        Sheets(1).Range(Cells(down_var, 3).Address).Value = 
.querySelector(tag_array(tag_array_index_no)).innerText
        Else
        Sheets(1).Range(Cells(down_var, 2).Address).Value = 
tag_array(tag_array_index_no)
        Sheets(1).Range(Cells(down_var, 3).Address).Value = 
tag_array(tag_array_index_no) + " not set."
        End If
        End With
```

I'm able to check if the tag exists in the response text.